# No Sound in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have a rather peculiar problem with sound. Recently, I re-installed Windows 7 on my PC and sound isn't working since then.

Upon clicking on the Volume icon in the taskbar, I notice that the audio device in use is **"Digital Audio (HDMI) (High Definition Audio Device)"**. When I click on it to go to its Properties window, under "Jack Information" it displays **"HDMI Digital Jack"**. Therein lies the source of the problem.

I do not have an HDMI Digital Jack installed. My speakers are connected via a standard 3.5mm audio jack. The speakers work fine, by the way, as I've tested them with an MP3 player.

There is only one playback device listed under Control Panel > Sounds - **"Digital Audio (HDMI)"**. Right-clicking and selecting "Show disabled devices" and "Show disconnected devices" produces no other results.

I tried re-installing the audio drivers (Uninstalled the sound controller from Device Manager, and installed driver package from Realtek) but to no avail. The sound controller still doesn't list as **"Realtek HD Audio"** or something similar (as I believe was the case prior to the Windows re-install).

My motherboard has an onboard sound card. Nothing fancy there.

How do I get the analog sound working again?

Comment: Are you using windows default audio drivers?
Get the specific ones from you MoBo manufacturer's website and try those.

Comment: First, I was. Then I uninstalled them and installed the ones from Realtek, as I've mentioned. The sound is still not working. Also, prior to the Windows re-install, the default drivers worked fine.